# warning when dissmiss the UIAlertView in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I get following warning-

```
 warning: passing argument 1 of 'dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:' makes integer from pointer without a cast

[alertForLoading dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:nil animated:YES];
```

Comment: why you are passing nil as argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated` expects a `NSInteger` as an argument and you are specifying nil.

Replace nil with the index of the button that you want to be pressed like this:

```
 [alertForLoading dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

"dismissWithClickedButtonIndex" is accepting any int number. this method calls following UIAlertViewDelegate method

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

see referance for more info : [UIAlertViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html)